TransferV1 + token-2022
I've been struggling for a while with a transferV1 transaction from the mpl-token-metadata library using the Umi interface. Many examples here and there show how to do it with the classic spl-token protocol, but I have the feeling that when it comes to token-2022, things get complicated...
The bottom line is that I'm "simply" trying to make a transaction that involves a "payment" of a defined amount, but in spl-token-2022, which is why I turned to transferV1 but maybe I'm going about it the wrong way. Instruction 2: custom program error: 0x39
umi.use(walletAdapterIdentity(wallet))
const sign = createSignerFromKeypair(umi, upgAuth);
umi.use(signerIdentity(sign, false));

let sourceATA = findAssociatedTokenPda(umi, { mint: TOKEN_REWARD, owner: umi.payer.publicKey, tokenProgramId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID });
    let destATA = findAssociatedTokenPda(umi, { mint: TOKEN_REWARD, owner: umi.identity.publicKey, tokenProgramId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID });
    sourceATA = new PublicKey(sourceATA[0]);
    destATA = new PublicKey(destATA[0]);
    transactions = transactions.add(
        transferV1(umi, {
            mint: TOKEN_REWARD,
            authority: umi.payer,
            tokenOwner: sourceATA,
            destinationOwner: destATA,
            tokenStandard: TokenStandard.Fungible,
            splTokenProgram: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
            amount: 10,
        })
    );

Everytime it ends up with the following error :
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: custom program error: 0x39 [...]
0x39 = Incorrect account owner 

What i'm i doing wrong ?

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/blob/main/clients/js/src/generated/instructions/transferV1.ts
If token and destinationToken parameters are not passed, transferV1 will call findAssociatedTokenPda without passing in any tokenProgramId, which defaults to the original Token Program.
if (!resolvedAccounts.token.value) {
  resolvedAccounts.token.value = findAssociatedTokenPda(context, {
    mint: expectPublicKey(resolvedAccounts.mint.value),
    owner: expectPublicKey(resolvedAccounts.tokenOwner.value),
  });
}

if (!resolvedAccounts.destinationToken.value) {
  resolvedAccounts.destinationToken.value = findAssociatedTokenPda(context, {
    mint: expectPublicKey(resolvedAccounts.mint.value),
    owner: expectPublicKey(resolvedAccounts.destinationOwner.value),
  });
}

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-toolbox/blob/7c252a1de09de9456f7e49dd71193df1357369f0/clients/js/src/hooked/AssociatedToken.ts#L4
const tokenProgramIdResolved =
  seeds.tokenProgramId ?? context.programs.getPublicKey('splToken');

You have to explicitly pass in token and destinationToken when transferring Token-2022 tokens, so that when findProgramAddressSync from umi is called internally, it creates the associated token accounts if it doesn't already exist.
const [token] = findAssociatedTokenPda(umi, {
  mint,
  owner: tokenOwner,
  tokenProgramId: SPL_TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
});

const [destinationToken] = findAssociatedTokenPda(umi, {
  mint,
  owner: destinationOwner,
  tokenProgramId: SPL_TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
});

await transferV1(umi, {
  mint,
  authority: umi.payer,
  token,
  destinationToken,
  tokenOwner,
  destinationOwner,
  tokenStandard: TokenStandard.Fungible,
  splTokenProgram: SPL_TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
  amount: amount * ATOMIC_UNITS_PER_TOKEN,
}).sendAndConfirm(umi);


I ended up using createTransferCheckedInstruction from spl-token library. Then used adapter fromWeb3jsInstruction which returns Instruction type (can not be appended to umi native transactions/TransactionBuilder) because it expects WrappedInstruction  type and not Instruction.
This is how to convert Instruction to Wrapped Instruction
  const transferFeeTx = createTransferCheckedInstruction(
    fungibleSourceTokenAccount,
    new Web3PublicKey(tokenAddress),
    fungibleTargetTokenAccount,
    new Web3PublicKey(umi.payer.publicKey),
    BigInt(amount * Math.pow(10, tokenDecimals)),
    tokenDecimals,
    undefined,
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
  );

  const umiFeeIx = fromWeb3JsInstruction(transferFeeTx);

  const wrapperUmiFeeIx: WrappedInstruction = {
    instruction: umiFeeIx,
    signers: [umi.payer],
    bytesCreatedOnChain: 0,
  };


I don't know if this is the right solution but it works just fine. In my case, I needed to append this instruction to a TransactionBuilder object.
